# Errors about the macro defination and header files

Tags: macros, header

I'm working on a project based on MSP430 microchip, using IAR compiler. Here is the **simplified problem**:

In my project I have 3 files:

In **clock.h:**

```
#define MCLK_8MHZ
void clk_init(void);
```

In **clock.c:**

```
#include "clock.h"
void clk_init(void)
{
    #ifdef MCLK_8MHZ
        #define delay_ms(x) __delay_cycles((long)(1000000*(double)x/1000.0))  
    #endif
    #ifdef MCLK_12MHZ
        ...
    #endif
}
```

In **main.c:**

```
#include "clock.h"
clk_init();
delay_ms(5);
```

And the compiler would say  **function "delay_ms" declared implicitly**

I think it mistook the delay_ms() as a function instead of a macro. Sure I could define it as a real function. But I thought it would damage the accuracy of time controlling.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need quotes around your include in main.c like:

```
#include "clock.h"
```

?

If that is your only warning, it's something else.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the quotes here, but I did use them in my project...It presents me an error when I try to link.